# How do I mark my Jenkins build status based on cucumber scenarios pass percentage?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, cucumber

I'm trying to mark Jenkins build status as failed if more than 10% of the cucumber scenarios have failed. if 90% has passed the build should be success.

I have referred to the cucumber reports documentations
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/cucumber-reports/
https://plugins.jenkins.io/cucumber-reports/
and have set

> failedScenariosPercentage : 10

but the build is marked as failed even if 1 scenario has failed.

weirdly in console I see it is logged that

> Found 0.496278 failed steps, while expected  not more than 0.000000
> present.
> Build status left unchanged.

I haven't set any checks on test steps.
The pipeline steps are as follows

```
 post {
        always {
            cucumber failedFeaturesNumber: -1,
            failedScenariosNumber: -1,
            skippedStepsNumber: -1,
            failedStepsNumber: -1,
            pendingStepsNumber:-1,
            undefinedStepsNumber: -1,
            fileIncludePattern: '**/*cucumber-report.json',
            sortingMethod: 'ALPHABETICAL',
            failedScenariosPercentage:10
        }
    }
```

Can someone tell me if I'm doing something wrong here?

Comment: 1) why would you want to allow 10% of failed tests? 2) why do you configure `-1` for all the numbers? I'm not sure how the plugin handles it internally but anyway I would expect that defining `failedScenariosPercentage`, `failedScenariosNumber` and `failedFeaturesNumber` will randomly affect the result. Also, you did not specify how many scenarios do you run - if there are 9-10 of them, this would also be expected.

Comment: 1) some thing I just want to try out, not sure if this would be feasible but wanted to explore. We have over 200 tests and getting a 100% pass seems impossible. 10 is just a number I gave for the sake of the question.
2) There are some rules that I need to skip before setting failedScenariosPercentage . That's why all the -1. They have been set after checking the documentation.